# Can you ever use “ever” with the past perfect?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

It is ever right to say:

> Had you ever visited the USA?

Or is *ever* only used with the present perfect:

> Have you ever visited the USA?

If you can use *ever* with the past perfect as well, then what is the shade of meaning that using it confers here which omitting it would not?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/420280/73636

Answer (score 3):

The past perfect *had* is always used as the older of two events that occurred in the past. E.g.:

> **Had** you **ever** visited the USA **before** you went to live in Mexico?

I know you went to live in Mexico (event 2), but I don't know if you ever visited the USA (event 1) before that. This is a perfectly valid use of *ever* with the past perfect.

By itself,

> **Had** you ever visited the USA?

can be valid if the conversation at that point is about some period in the past, e.g. if the conversation is about when you were living in Mexico.

If we say:

> **Have** you ever visited the USA?

we are asking about any time in the past, or in other words before now, or before the present.